# In Android 7.0 appium launches the app but wont perform further actions

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I am automating android native apps using appium. Appium is working fine across all devices which has versions less than 7.0, but when I run appium on version 7.0 or more, appium launches the app but wont perfom further actions(appium wont stop execution, it will freeze at that point after launching app).

Please refer below appium logs.

```
        disc='loginScreen_createAccountSelectorButton']","4e69a744-5030-426e-a666-539ec0dc6ef7"]
        [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
        [debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, -android uiautomator
        [debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
        [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.TextViewp[@conent-disc='loginScreen_createAccountSelectorButton']","context":"","multiple":false}}
        [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.TextViewp[@conent-disc='loginScreen_createAccountSelectorButton']","context":"","multiple":false}}
        [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
        [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
        [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding '//android.widget.TextViewp[@conent-disc='loginScreen_createAccountSelectorButton']' using 'XPATH' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
```

If you see last line of the log, appium trie's to find the element but and the appium server will not stop, it will be running for ever. Please help to make it run on the android devices which has version more than 7.0.

Comment: Update your Appium software.

Comment: @BillHileman I am using latest appium(version 1.7.1). But also I am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your issue, you need to update your Android 7.0 SDK. You can do it by navigating in Android Studio to **Help => Check for Updates**.

You can also install required version of SDK by navigating to SDK Manager and select the SDK from the list and install it.

**Note:**

I am able to execute tests on my Android 7.0 device effortlessly as I keep my Appium and Android up-to-date.

Comment: I do have same problem.I have written automation script with Java,Appium and application is developed using React native. 
I Did following things                                                                                                  I have updated android SDK 
I have 1.7.1 Appium       Still have same problem.

Comment: Try using latest Appium server 1.9.0 and Java client 6.1.0. If this doesn't solve your issue, you can raise a new question with details and share the link to that question here. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your replay I tried the your suggestions. Still have same issue I will raise a new issue.